# Looks like I get margin on the box

Tags: html, css, navigation, sidebar, margins

HTML code:

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta ncharset="utf-8"/>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width", initial scale=1/>
        <meta name="description" content="Oficijalni sajt Karate kluba Splinter iz Beograda."/>

    <title>Karate klub Splinter</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
    <body>

    </body>
    <div id="sidebar">
        <div class="logo"></div>
        <nav>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">123</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">123</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">123</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">123</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">123</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">123</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">123</a></li>

            </ul>

        </nav>


        <div id="social">
            <h3>Pratite nas</h3>
            <div class="icons">
                <div class="fb-icon"></div>
                <div class="insta-icon"></div>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>



    </head>
</html>
```

CSS code:

```css
#sidebar{
    width:20%;
    height:100%;
    background:#2c3e50;
    margin:0;

}
```

All I want is sidebar that is going to fid left right corner without margins so after I can add content to the right side easily.When I test code I mentioned above I get div which is separated from start of the page and I

Comment: you should add your css to the question, it will be hard to troubleshoot without it

Comment: I did, give a look at the bottom of code

Comment: like this if you add to css: body{margin:0;} ?

Comment: yeah, absolutely forgout about it.thank you very much